# Error 1046 : 3D000 No Database selected while importing sql file

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am new to Mariadb and I am trying to import an sql file to Mariadb Linux server but I am getting the above error.

I move to the directory where I have my .sql file and

Command that I used is

```
mysql --user=school --password=mypass --default_character_set=utf8 < school_bus.sql
```

This command is giving me the above error.

I have already created the database named 
schoolbustrack in mysql shell.

I am using Mariadb 5.5.52.

**EDIT:**

I tried this command by making a new user

```
 mysql -u school -p schoolbustrack < school_bus.sql
```

also I used the command below

```
 mysql --user=school --password=mypass --default_character_set=utf8 -p schoolbustrack < school_bus.sql
```

using both the above commands I am getting below error.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 29: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '6), `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1' at line 5
```

Comment: You can see the command I have used in my edit section.

Comment: Does it work for you now?

Comment: Tukan you can find the sql file here https://pastebin.com/3VshkwJM

Comment: You have there multiple errors.  I have managed to fix all the errors and loaded your script into my testing instance.  Since this is out of scope of the original question, please accept this question first.  If you create a new question I'll gladly upload the fixed script for you.

Comment: But I have to check whether it is working at my end and still my problem isn't resolved, how can I accept your answer.

Comment: You can verify that you are at the correct database by by running `mysql --user=school --password=mypass --default_character_set=utf8 --database=schoolbustrack`.  Then you will see `MariaDB [schoolbustrack]>` at the MariaDB shell.  That means you are using `schoolbustrack` which was your original question.

Comment: You can't cut down the actual command and say its working , I have to test with the sql file which was my orginal question.

Comment: Actually you have asked a question where you were getting an let me quote your topic title: `Error 1046 : 3D000 No Database selected while importing sql file`.  You are the one who ones help and I ask you not much in return. (You have added `-p schoolbustrack` which was NOT part of the original question).  That would mean you could get unlimited help on one question if you do re-edits.  Sorry that is not how stackoverflow works.  You ask question you get best answer possible.  You have another issue you ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing selection of the DB `USE database_name;`.

**EDIT:**
You can also specify it in the command line (adding `--database=database_name` OR `-D database_name`)

I see the Mariadb has changed considerably from mysql now.  The command line switch is different.  I had to install your version of MariaDB.  Now the answer is tested it on my dev instance.

I'm using your command line:
`mysql --user=school --password=mypass --default_character_set=utf8 --database=database_name < school_bus.sql`

Comment: I am getting this error ,  ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 29: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '6),  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1' at line 5

Comment: Hi tukan , sorry to say but u have introduced me with a new error

Comment: @Ashish: sorry about that I had to install your version of MariaDB.  Please see the edit.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but I am still getting the exact same error :(

Comment: @AshishShukla:  Well that is now the error of the `.sql` file you are trying to import and not the command line itself. The error is around: `6), 'is_active' tinyint(1) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1' at line 5`.  Since you did provide the content of your `school_bus.sql` without any sensitive information, I can not help you till you do so (but that is different question thou).

Comment: Give your email I'd I will send it you.

Comment: @AshishShukla: Why to use email?  Either paste it here or to some service like `https://pastebin.com` or some anonymous sharing sites like `https://filetea.me` - and then send me the link.